# Accessing/Changing Information in Tables with Javascript

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I am using greasemonkey to change the functionality of an existing web page.. If you aren't familiar with greamonkey it doesn't really matter.. the main information is that the current code for the existing page looks like this:

```
<div id="sqlDiv" class="sqlBorderDiv" style="display: none;">
<div class="reportBorderDiv">
    <table class="reportTable">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <tr class="reportRow1">
            <tr class="reportRow2">
                <td>55555</td>
                <td>Bruce Wayne</td>
                <td>12456789123</td>
                <td>2013-12-17</td>
                <td>Batman</td>
                <td>Superhero</td>
                <td>Menace</td>
                <td>123246</td>
                <td>12456</td>
                <td>123456</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I want to run a script on it that will make the first cell of any reportRow into a hyperlink using the information in that cell. I am trying with a script like below, but something is going wrong and I have no idea what. ( I am really new into javascript). Thank you for any suggestions!!

```
var anchor = null;
var container;
var rows;
var cells;
var demoNum;
var linkString = "https://somewebsite.com/";

container = document.getElementById('sq1Div');

rows = container.getElementsByTagName("tr"); 

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) { 
    var className = rows[i].getAttribute("class"); 
    if ( className == "reportRow1" || className == "reportRow2" ) { 
        anchor = rows[i];
        cells = anchor.getElementsByTagName("td");
        demoNum = cells[0];
        linkString = linkString + demoNum;
        cells[0] = <a href = linkString > demoNum </a>;    
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the error console? What error message does it give?

Comment: how do i find the error console?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Open tools>Web Developer>Browser console.

Comment: So No errors are showing up

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the line

`cells[0] = <a href = linkString > demoNum </a>;`

That should be in a string, like this:

`cells[0]="<a href='"+linkstring+"'>"+demonum+"</a>";`

To put that back in the first row of the table, you can do this

```
row[i].childNodes[0].innerHTML=cells[0];
```

Also, you have `document.getElementById("sq1div")`, instead of `"sqlDiv"`

Comment: even with these changes there are no changes to the table displayed on the page. just for clarification, why does it have to be in a string?

Comment: Otherwise it will treat <a as a constant, and it won't know how to interpret it

Comment: oh that makes sense. :) so I made those two changes, and it still isn't working. I have also tried changing the script so just demoNum changes to 000 and that isn't working either.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById('sq**1**Div');

incorrect indetifier, you are using number "1" instead of letter "l"

and of course as wrote scrblnrd3 line with new link builds incorrect

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the HTML has unmatched  tags, could this somehow confuse greasemonkey?

Comment: The first chunk of code is just a very small part of a firebug block that pertains to the section I'm working with.. It is actually a gigantic table with lots of rows, so I just expanded one of them to show what the format is.